# Check if new edge will make DAG cyclic

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

Given some directed graph there are a lot of algorithms for checking weather or not it contains cycles. i.e. algorithms with signatures like this:

```
function isCyclic(g: DirectedGraph): bool
```

But I have a problem which is a little different: Given a directed graph that I already know is acyclic I want to check if adding a given edge will create a cycle. i.e. something like this:

```
function willCreateCycle(g: AcyclicDirectedGraph, newEdge: Edge): bool
```

My solution this far:

In the graph we have some nodes, two of which are F (from) and T (to)
We want to check if adding a new edge E = F->T will create a cycle

=>

Traverse the graph starting from node T. If we at any point end up at node F we have a cycle.

Do you think this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is correct. Adding an edge F->T will result in a cycle if and only if there exists already a path from T to F.